# SQL subquery syntax assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get specific values from a query in one database in separate columns.

If I run the following query:

```
select  ticker 
        ,calendardate 
        ,marketcap
        ,dimension
from [Investment Data 1].dbo.sf1a
where 
        ticker = 'aapl' 
    and dimension in ('ary','mry')
    and calendardate >='2013-01-01'
order by dimension, calendardate;
```

I get the following result:

```
ticker  calendardate    marketcap   dimension
AAPL    2013-12-31  472272497794    ARY
AAPL    2014-12-31  616453338265    ARY
AAPL    2015-12-31  664969711644    ARY
AAPL    2013-12-31  438576934018    MRY
AAPL    2014-12-31  603277600250    MRY
AAPL    2015-12-31  654159234917    MRY
```

I want a query that will return the following result:

```
ticker  calendardate    "ARY Marketcap" "MRY Marketcap"
AAPL    2013-12-31      472272497794    438576934018    
AAPL    2014-12-31      616453338265    603277600250    
AAPL    2015-12-31      664969711644    654159234917
```

How can I do this?

Thanks for your time.  Wised.

Comment: I'm confused by title and content. Where is subquery? How is it related to syntax? It's not a SSMS question either. BTW, search `PIVOT`.

Comment: You either can write an old school pivot query, or use SQL Server's `PIVOT` operator.

Comment: Are `(ticker, calendardate, dimension)` unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `case expression` allows you to perform `conditional aggregates` and this has the effect of a `pivot` from rows to columns

```
select  ticker 
        ,calendardate 
        ,max(case when dimension = 'ary' then marketcap end) as aryMarketcap
        ,max(case when dimension = 'mry' then marketcap end) as mryMarketcap
from [Investment Data 1].dbo.sf1a
where 
        ticker = 'aapl' 
    and dimension in ('ary','mry')
    and calendardate >='2013-01-01'
group by  ticker 
        ,calendardate 
order by dimension, calendardate;
```

alternative is to use a the `pivot` operator

```
select
      ticker, calendardate, [ary], [mry]
from (select 
            * 
       from table1) p
pivot (
    max(marketcap)
    for dimension IN ([ary],[mry])
    ) pvt
```

If you have many dimension that you want to pivot into column headings, you may need to use `dynamic sql` to achieve the final result.